# How is "T" declared in R?

Tags: r

In R, the "T" is a variable that represents TRUE. However, when I examined the memory addresses of both "T" and "TRUE", they were distinct.

```
library(lobstr)
obj_addr(T)
[1] "0x7f0c644662a0"
obj_addr(TRUE)
[1] "0x7f0c1b1c92d8"
```

How is "T" defined in R?"

Comment: `?T` :   "TRUE and FALSE are reserved words denoting logical constants in the R language, whereas T and F are global variables whose initial values set to these. All four are logical(1) vectors." So T starts as a global variable set to TRUE, but one could use `T <- FALSE` to change that without changing TRUE.

Comment: @JonSpring And to set `TRUE <- FALSE` or to any other value throws an error, *"Error in TRUE <- FALSE : invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment"*.

Comment: Using `T` and `F` is just bad practice and it was a mistake to create them. I assume they are a legacy from S. Nowadays, if we didn't already have them, R-core would never create them.

Comment: To further clarify John's comment: `T` is a symbol to which a length-one logical vector is bound. `TRUE` is a length-one logical vector that isn't bound to a symbol. That's why the memory addresses differ. Interestingly, this is fundamentally different to `N <- NULL; obj_addr(N); obj_addr(NULL)` because there is only one `NULL` object whereas `TRUE` creates a new logical vector each time.

Comment: How can we check the predefined global variables like `T` in R?

Comment: What do you mean by check? `stopifnot(identical(TRUE, T))`?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, objects in R (such as `T`, `TRUE`, `NaN`, `Inf` and `pi`) can be copied to another memory location.

As @Roland says in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77192116/how-the-t-statement-is-declared-in-r/77193238?noredirect=1#comment136083144_77192116), one exception is `NULL`. This is set out in the [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.pdf) (p. 5):

> There is only one NULL object in R, to which all instances refer.

The documentation also sets out that environments act in a similar fashion (p. 11):

> Unlike most other R objects, environments are not copied when passed to functions or used in assignments. Thus, if you assign the same environment to several symbols and change one, the others will change too.

We can write a function to test this using [`rlang::duplicate()`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/rlang/html/duplicate.html).

```r
library(lobstr)
is_singleton_instance <- function(symb) {
    symb_copy  <- rlang::duplicate(symb)
    obj_addr(symb) == obj_addr(symb_copy)
}

is_singleton_instance(NULL) # TRUE
is_singleton_instance(TRUE) # FALSE
is_singleton_instance(emptyenv()) # TRUE
```

Also as the comments state, you can reassign to `T` and `F` but not to `TRUE` and `FALSE`. Again we can write a function to see which built-in constants we can change:

```r
can_reassign <- function(symb) {
    # Don't try to reassign if provided emptyenv() etc.
    if (grepl("\\(\\)$", symb)) {
        return(NA)
    }
    can_reassign <- try(
        eval(
            parse(text = sprintf("%s <- TRUE", symb))
        )
    )
    class(can_reassign) != "try-error"
}
```

Here are the results:

```
| symbol            | is_singleton  | can_reassign  |
|---------------    |-------------- |-------------- |
| NULL              | TRUE          | FALSE         |
| NA                | FALSE         | FALSE         |
| NA_integer_       | FALSE         | FALSE         |
| NA_character_     | FALSE         | FALSE         |
| NA_complex_       | FALSE         | FALSE         |
| NA_real_          | FALSE         | FALSE         |
| NaN               | FALSE         | FALSE         |
| Inf               | FALSE         | FALSE         |
| -Inf              | FALSE         | FALSE         |
| 1                 | FALSE         | FALSE         |
| 0                 | FALSE         | FALSE         |
| TRUE              | FALSE         | FALSE         |
| FALSE             | FALSE         | FALSE         |
| T                 | FALSE         | TRUE          |
| F                 | FALSE         | TRUE          |
| pi                | FALSE         | TRUE          |
| letters           | FALSE         | TRUE          |
| LETTERS           | FALSE         | TRUE          |
| month.abb         | FALSE         | TRUE          |
| month.name        | FALSE         | TRUE          |
| .GlobalEnv        | TRUE          | TRUE          |
| list()            | FALSE         | NA            |
| environment()     | TRUE          | NA            |
| baseenv()         | TRUE          | NA            |
| emptyenv()        | TRUE          | NA            |
| globalenv()       | TRUE          | NA            |
| logical()         | FALSE         | NA            |
| raw()             | FALSE         | NA            |
```

##### Weird footnote

`NA_character_` acts a bit oddly.

```r
NA_integer_  <- 1
# Error in NA_integer_ <- 1 : invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment
NA_integer_
[1] NA
NA_character_  <- TRUE
# No error. However...
NA_character_
# [1] NA
```

##### Input list

This was the list of objects I used to test this.

```r
symbs <- list(
    "NULL" = NULL,
    "NA" = NA,
    "NA_integer_" = NA_integer_,
    "NA_character_" = NA_character_,
    "NA_complex_" = NA_complex_,
    "NA_real_" = NA_real_,
    "NaN" = NaN,
    "Inf" = Inf,
    "-Inf" = -Inf,
    "1" = 1,
    "0" = 0,
    "TRUE" = TRUE,
    "FALSE" = FALSE,
    "T" = T,
    "F" = F,
    "pi" = pi,
    "letters" = letters,
    "LETTERS" = LETTERS,
    "month.abb" = month.abb,
    "month.name" = month.name,
    ".GlobalEnv" = .GlobalEnv,
    "list()" = list(),
    "environment()" = environment(),
    "baseenv()" = baseenv(),
    "emptyenv()" = emptyenv(),
    "globalenv()" = globalenv(),
    "logical()" = logical(),
    "raw()" = raw()
)
is_singleton <- sapply(symbs, is_singleton_instance)
can_reassign <- sapply(names(symbs), can_reassign)
data.frame(symbol = names(symbs), is_singleton, can_reassign)
```

Comment: Interesting find about `NA_character_`. A bug in the R parser.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm not convinced it is a bug and certainly it's not a parser bug. `<-` allows character strings on the LHS and `NA_character_` is technically a character string. All other `NA` types are not character strings or symbols and thus we get an error from `<-`. You can retrieve the value with `get(NA_character_)`.

Comment: @Roland I think your diagnosis is correct, but I maintain that this is *still* a parser bug, or at least undesired behaviour of the parser (caused by R’s idiotic idiosyncrasy of allowing character literals in place of names in some [but not all] places). — Incidentally, you don’t need `get(NA_character_)`: `get("NA")` also works (even though `NA_character_ ≠ "NA"`, by definition). ‍♂️

Comment: … and so does `\`NA\``

Answer (score 3):

`T` is a regular variable in R.

In fact, it’s defined [in the ‘base’ R package in a file `R/Rprofile`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b1ca1a7287d1263ac8569dc0f57dc72be6a65714/src/library/profile/Makefile.in#L20) [as follows](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b1ca1a7287d1263ac8569dc0f57dc72be6a65714/src/library/profile/Common.R#L15):

```
T <- TRUE
```

(Same for `F`.)

This is a regular assignment, so it creates a new vector object, which sits at a new memory location and therefore has a unique address.

As Roland noted in the comments, the exception to this is when assigning `NULL`, since that doesn’t create a new vector object. Another special case are environments, which are *reference objects*, and are therefore also not copied upon assignment.

Comment: I realised from this answer that my answer made a mistake with environments - I was comparing the `obj_addr()` of `emptyenv()` with the address of `list(emptyenv())`. I've updated it now - thanks.